# Time delay @future method - need delay for recurring batch process to complete

Tags: rest-api, future, salesforce2salesforce, restresource

I have the following requirement and am looking for advice for the best way to process it.

We have multiple orgs linked to each other via S2S, with batch jobs running every 10min to pass updates between them.

I have an account for which a child custom record X is created in an 'awaiting' status. The account is shared between the orgs, but record X is only shared to the spoke orgs when the status changes to 'active'. This sharing is the batch run that runs every 10min.

The change on X to status 'active' is triggered by an update from an external 3rd party to my @RestResource apex class. This update also includes attaching a PDF, which is returned from the 3rd party, to record X.

My problem is the API call to share the PDF runs immediately on update from the 3rd party, whereas the creation of X in the spoke org can be anywhere from immediate to max 10 min later, when S2S runs, as that is created by the S2S process. The code does a query looking for the ID in X.

So what I need to do is delay the sharing of the PDF by max 10min, or until record X exists in the spoke org so I can attach it to X.

What is the best way to do this?

1. Can I delay the @future process that does the callout to the spoke org (http) and passes the PDF for 10min to ensure X will exist in the spoke org when I pass the PDF, or
2. should I put a time loop in the code where it receives the PDF in the spoke org (a SOQL looking for the ID on X) until record X has been passed/created (max 10min - fail if more)?

The @future method also updates the hub record X based on the Http response from the callout - says whether the update in the spoke org has succeeded or failed based on the return StatusCode. So I'm also not sure if option 2 would work if it takes 10min to respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone with a scheduled batch process to share the PDF to the other orgs as delaying @future doesn't seem possible. The batch process starts a few min after the initial update, and in the finish section of the batch process I recheck and re-schedule for another 10min. This is tested and working.